# Creating different tab pairs in vim

Tags: vim, formatting, tabstop

Vim newbie here.

I would like to be able to create tabs in Vim such that, for example, the tabs are at 4" left and 1.5" right for one type of section, 1.5"/1.5" for another, etc.

I know how to set tab stops, etc. but the trick here is I would like vim to recognize key combinations like shift-enter to go to one kind of formatting, plain enter to go to another kind, etc.

Is this even possible with vim?

TIA

Comment: Yeah, the inches ain't gonna happen. If you settle for spaces instead of physical measures, vim can do.

Comment: Really? I'm fine with an approximation of the inches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these screenplay scripts. At least the first one contains custom tab widths as required in the traditional play formats. Perhaps they provide you the right idea on what's possible with Vim:

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2447 by Mike Zazaian
- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1842 by Alex Lance

Comment: Wow. I'll try those out. What I'm really looking for is something that can do stageplay format, not screenplay, but I can fiddle with the scripts (no, uh, pun intended) to get the margins right. Ultimately, anything that produces a text file whose formatting is close enough to allow easy merging with an existing MMSW script will be good.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing Vim with a word processor (like *Word* or *Writer*). There's no measurement in inches, no left / right margins, etc.

Vim's `'tabstop'` option is a multiple of the width of a single space character that a `<Tab>` character (ASCII 0x09) expands to. This is fixed for the entire buffer (though you could use a set of `:autocmd`s to change it in different parts of a buffer). Vim has no notion of *paragraph text styles* like a word processor, where you can define different styles. Vim only has a rather primitive `:hardcopy` command for printing.

If you need elaborate text formatting capabilities, Vim probably is the wrong tool, except if you choose to edit a source code document (like *Latex*, HTML, or *Markdown*), which is only *compiled* into a document (for those, like editing programming languages, it's actually well suited and powerful).

The `vimtutor` command (see `:help vimtutor` inside Vim) provides a good introduction to Vim's capabilities.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case. I was actually aware that "inches" would be impossible - I would be fine with an approximation.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: See progo's comment. Apparently it is possible after all. :)

Comment: I couldn't deduce from your general question that you're interested in writing plays. Those plugins contort Vim in a way that I've hinted at. I'm glad you've managed to express what you're actually looking for, and have found something! Happy Vimming :-)